# Center align anchor within a `li` element?

Tags: css, alignment

So I have a simple list thats set out like below

```
<ul class='my-videos'>
   <li>
       <a class='show-more' href='' title=''>Show More</a>
   </li>
<ul>
```

I am trying to get the `.show-more` to be center aligned. I have got this far

```
ul.my-videos li .show-more
{
   display:inline-block;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Now this doesn't work. I have setup a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/6HHKf/

Any ideas on this?

PS I want to keep the anchor as `inline` or `inline-block` so that the width isn't 100%

**UPDATE**
There are other elements in the `li`, so `text-align` is out of the answer

Comment: Why does this have six downvotes and a close vote? I don't see anything wrong with it. Does the phrase "doesn't work" trigger automatic downvotes or something?

Comment: I wonder. Sometimes SO have real douchebags. The questions seems just fine to me. Actually, it even helped me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ul.my-videos li .show-more {
    margin:0 auto;
    border:#aaa 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

if you want center an element width `margin: 0 auto` you need to set the `width`

and also, you need `display:block`

check jsfiddle here:   http://jsfiddle.net/6HHKf/5/

Comment: Thanks very much. Works a treat

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the CSS for the list item to center align the text.

```
.my-videos li { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: *Mod note:* comments are not for bickering over who's right, who's wrong and who deserves to be downvoted. If a question was slightly edited but to the point of invalidating or obsoleting your answer, either edit your answer along or remove it altogether. If you feel the question edit completely and utterly changes the content or overall meaning of the question (which I'm pretty sure didn't happen to *this* question), leave a comment, or in serious cases roll it back. If you want to start conversations here, keep them constructive and professional; don't bicker or name-call.

Comment: Also: if somebody is editing or vandalizing their question *with the sole intent of downvoting all the answers*, that would constitute abuse worthy of a flag, but that isn't the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just add `text-align:center;` to the `li`.

### Edit

Since you need to cope with other mystery elements in the li this may work http://jsfiddle.net/6HHKf/6/

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option to use an extra span within the `a` element, you could use relative positioning with `left +/- 50%`

http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/6HHKf/8/